# Magento displays price of configurable product instead of simple product

Tags: php, magento, configurable-product

With an import script I created configurable products in Magento. The price of the configurable product is displayed on the frontend, which is not what I want of course. I want to show the price of the selected simple product.

On the product detail page, when I change the configurable attribute, the price is not updated. The price of the configurable products is always visible. Also, when I add the product to the cart, the configurable product price is displayed.

When I add each simple product of a configurable product to the cart, it still displays the configurable product price. I can see that there are different products in the cart, so the problem is not that it is always putting the same simple product in the cart.

How can I fix this? Where do I start looking?
I don't know what caused this, because another company made this webshop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After product import execution, try Indexing product catalog and check If that can help you.

Comment: Depending on what extensions you have, Magento does this by default with configurable products. Magento takes the base price of the configurable product, and adds/subtracts based on what you set the price differences to be based on the options under its associated products tab. In order for Magento to take the simple product price directly you'll need an extension for that.

Comment: Rajiv, I already reindexed everything so that cannot be the problem. Jason, I thought that the way how I want it is the default. So how can I fix it now? I have to install an extension? Which one? This one works but it does strange things with the taxes and it doesn't display the configurable attribute anymore in the cart: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html